# Is my sudoku algorithm valid?

Tags: sudoku

i am trying to make a sudoku generator. My approach is to have an array of 81 elements with each element being itself an array of numbers 1-9, representing every possibility for each square. My planned approach is to go through each square in sequence, randomly picking a number from the available numbers and deleting all other copies of that number in that row, column, or sub square. For example, if I pick a 4 for the very first square, then I remove all 4's from the other squares of the first row, the first column, and the first sub-square.

I'm wondering if this is a good approach. It obviates the need for number verification, as the only pickable numbers will be the legal ones that remain. My concern is that if I get halfway through and run out of numbers, then I will have to backtrack to the beginning, and that it'll take the age of the Universe to generate a puzzle. What do you think? I know there are other approaches that work, but I am curious to see if mine is valid.

thanks.

Comment: why is there a "-1" next to this question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this algorithm seems to be valid.  I do not see, however, why you would need to backtrack.  The way you described it, it should not run out of numbers to use until it's all filled up.

Answer (score 0):

Having advanced a bit with this, I've found that sometimes the individual squares do run out of numbers, meaning I have to go back to the start because backtracking would be absurdly complex. I'm going to abandon this algorithm and try to do this based on this guy's algorithm

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23206/Sudoku-Algorithm-Generates-a-Valid-Sudoku-in?msg=5144381#xx5144381xx